# PHP imap - get messages received last hour

Tags: php, imap

I'm writing a little imap class and want to fetch mails which have been received during the last hour, but can't find a solution for this.

I've found the possibility of `imap_search()` which is working, but only for dates:

```
    $date = date ( "d M Y", strToTime ( "- 1 days" ) );
    $this->date = imap_search ( $connection, "SINCE \"$date\"");
```

When doing

```
    $date = date ( "d M Y h:i", strToTime ( "- 1 hours" ) );
    $this->date = imap_search ( $connection, "SINCE \"$date\"");
```

it gives me the examt same result as with the first approach, but not only messages received during the last hour.

Same result for

```
g   12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 1 through 12
G   24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23
h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
i   Minutes with leading zeros  00 to 59
s   Seconds, with leading zeros 00 through 59
```

Does somebody know what I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMAP Protocol does not support a time based search, only days.

You could do a date based search, then fetch the INTERNALDATE for those, and select the ones you want.

Alternatively if this is a process you are doing every hour, just track the UID of the newest message you have, and fetch any messages with higher UIDs.

Comment: Thank you! I thought about the UIDs, too. I've been looking around for the easiest way to get them, can you name it?

Comment: UID SEARCH UID (lastuidyouhave):*

Answer (score 1):

there is no option to get emails using hours. but you can use it based on days.
i wrote a solution for getting hourly emails
here i am sharing that with you

```
$mailbox =  "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$imapResource = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password);
$search = 'SINCE "' . date("j F Y", strtotime("0 days")) . '"';
$emails = imap_search($imapResource, $search);            
$emails = array_reverse($emails);

if(!empty($emails)){
                //Loop through the emails.
                foreach($emails as $email){
                    //Fetch an overview of the email.
                    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($imapResource, $email);
                  
                    $overview = $overview[0];
                    //Print out the subject of the email.
            
                    if(isset($overview->subject))
                    {
                        $emailsub =  htmlentities($overview->subject);
                    }
                   
                    //Print out the sender's email address / from email address.
                    $emailfrm = $overview->from;
                    
                    $string = $emailfrm;
                    $pattern = '/<(.*?)>/i';
                
                    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
                    $emailidfrom = $matches[1][0] ?? $string;
                     
    
    
                    
                    //Get the body of the email.
                   $message = imap_fetchbody($imapResource, $email, 1, FT_PEEK);

                   $unixTimestamp=strtotime($overview->date);
                   $mailtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);

                   $start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//set time here
                   $fromtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-60 minutes',strtotime($start)));

                         

                    if (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{76} )+[a-zA-Z0-9]{76}$/', $message)) {
                        $message = base64_decode($message);
                    }

                    echo "<div class='faq-tile'>$message</div>";

                         if($mailtime>$fromtime)
                       {
                        
                        // store to database

                          $message = nl2br($message);
                         $message = trim($message);
                         echo $message;
                      //  $message = htmlspecialchars($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                       
                 






                   //save to database 

                 

                    }

                   
                       }  

                 } 

                  
            }
```